# Swift/Spritekit create multiple instances

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Currently working on a game, and am stuck with how to best spawn multiple instances of the same `Monster`. In this example, my `Ogre` class is of type `Monster`, and i use the `spawn` function in my `Monster` class to create new instances. The only problem is i've hardcoded the `Ogre` class in the spawn method like so:

```
func spawn(scene: SKScene, number: Int) {
    for _ in 1...number {
        let ogre = Ogre()
        scene.addChild(ogre)
    }
}
```

Obviously, this won't work for spawning different types of enemies, what i would like to do is call spawn like `Monster.spawn(scene: self, type: SomeMonster, number: 5)` and have the spawn function more like:

```
func spawn(scene: SKScene, number: Int) {
    for _ in 1...number {
        let monster = node
        scene.addChild(monster)
    }
}
```

So how can I pass different Monsters into that function to spawn multiples of them? Would it be possible to pass the object as a param of the function like `spawn(monster: Ogre)` or maybe override the spawn function in each class of type `Monster` and then somehow create new instances of that class?

Really, i think my main issue is I simply don't know how to create a new instance of class without knowing explicitly what it is and hardcoding it. Any ideas and suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: So in essence you want to instantiate different types of monsters, without knowing which type you're actually instantiating? Or would you like to `addChild` different types without knowing which types you're adding?

Comment: both.. i think? the spawn function wouldn't know what specific type of monster it's adding, as long as it's of type `Monster`. but in my scene (for now) i plan to spawn enemies by calling `Monster.spawn(scene:self, type: SomeMonster, number: 5)` and `Monster.spawn(scene:self, type: AnotherMonster, number: 5)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: For adding spawning different kinds of monsters, you can pass an `enum` in your `Monster.spawn( ..)` function, use a `switch` statement, instantiate the object, and at the end add it to the scene. (you should definitely move this function out of the `Monster` class though)

Comment: hmm that way definitely makes sense in theory... i have been avoiding doing that for the monsters though, because there could be A LOT of different types. So i'm hoping to find a better way than to always be adding new enum types. Why do you say I should move the `spawn` function out of the `Monster` class?

Comment: Actually I think I misunderstood. `Monster` is your parent class and `Ogre` and `troll` would be its child classes, and you want to create these objects in the parent class, right?

Comment: yeah exactly !!

Comment: When you say that there could be a lot of different `Monster` types, what differentiates one type from another?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your `Monster` class

```
func spawn<T: Monster>(scene: SKScene, number: Int, monsterClass: T.Type) {
    for _ in 1...number {
        let monster = monsterClass.init()
        scene.addChild(monster)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe he want static func?

Comment: very interesting! This looks like the kind of solution i want, however, i get the error `'type' is not a member type of 'T'`. Any ideas? I've never seen this part `<T: Monster>` so i'm not quite sure what it's doing. Some kind of casting?

Comment: I have updated the code. There was a typo in `T.Type`. This function uses generics. You can read more about them here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#